# How to load _id Data from mongodb into Apache Pig

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, github, apache-pig

I am new in Hadoop  and Apache Pig.
I have a collection in mongodb named as user having following structure.I want to load _id into Apache Pig through:

```
B = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test.user' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader ('_id:chararray,firstName:chararray,email:chararray') AS (UID,NAME,EMAIL);
```

But i am unable to load it.name and email is loaded perfectly.

i am using these jar files

```
REGISTER /<path>/avro-1.7.5.jar
REGISTER /<path>/json-simple-1.1.jar
REGISTER /<path>/piggybank.jar
REGISTER /<path>/mongo-2.10.0.jar;
REGISTER /<path>/mongo-hadoop-core-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
REGISTER /<path>/mongo-hadoop-pig-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
REGISTER /<path>/mongo-hadoop-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

The structure of user collection is as follows

```
   {
"_class" : "UserInfo",
"_id" : ObjectId("51daf2ffed4d31f6"),
"assignments" : 0,
"contests" : 0,
"contes" : 0,
"email" : "princ@bank.com",
"firstName" : "Princessj",
"freeUploadsAllowed" : 2,
"freeUploadsDone" : 0,
"guideViewCount" : 0,
"hofAssignment" : 0,
"hofContest" : 0,
"inviteCount" : 0,
"issueType" : 0,
```

}

How it is possible please help me.

Comment: Pass some id alias as second parameter of MongoLoader. See details on idAlias here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/pig/README.md

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Thanks for response but i tried it like this  B = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test.user' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader ('id,firstName:chararray,email:chararray','id') AS (UID,NAME,EMAIL);and i got this error: Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:<file uservideo.pig, line 23, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader' with arguments '[id,firstName:chararray,email:chararray, id]' at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:196)

Answer (score 0):

From [Pig Usage](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage)

All you need to do is set alias as 'id'

> raw = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/demo.yield_historical.in' using com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader('id, bc10Year', 'id');